# Mysql couldn't get all rows when some fields are NULL in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html

Below is my mysql syntax, suppose there is null in field 'SecondName' or 'FamilyName' then no all rows are displayed. HELP?

```
   $result = mysql_query("select * from ident right join list_country on ident.CountryID =list_country.CountryID WHERE 



   ident.FirstName LIKE '%$first_name%' AND 
   ident.SecondName LIKE '%$second_name%' AND
   ident.Sex LIKE '%$sex%' AND  
   ident.DOB LIKE '%$dob%' AND  
   ident.FamilyName LIKE '%$family_name%' AND
   ident.SpouseName LIKE '%$spouse_name%' AND
   ident.FathersName LIKE '%$father_name%' AND      
   ident.MothersName LIKE '%$mother_name%' AND  
   ident.City LIKE '%$city_town%' AND    
   ident.CountryID LIKE '%$country_id%'");
```

Comment: thats because you are doing 'right join'.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query a little like below:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from ident right join list_country on ident.CountryID =list_country.CountryID WHERE 
   ident.FirstName LIKE '%$first_name%' AND 
   (ident.SecondName LIKE '%$second_name%' OR ident.SecondName IS NULL) AND
   ident.Sex LIKE '%$sex%' AND  
   ident.DOB LIKE '%$dob%' AND  
   (ident.FamilyName LIKE '%$family_name%' OR ident.FamilyName IS NULL) AND
   ident.SpouseName LIKE '%$spouse_name%' AND
   ident.FathersName LIKE '%$father_name%' AND      
   ident.MothersName LIKE '%$mother_name%' AND   
   ident.City LIKE '%$city_town%' AND    
   ident.CountryID LIKE '%$country_id%'");
```

Comment: @user3181614: it should work perfectly. still having problem?

Comment: Nope sir, you are correct, but is it possible to get exactly value suppose If I type Suresh Kamrushi and your family name.